# System Event log for Windows CE 5.0 and above

Tags: .net, compact-framework, windows-ce

I am investigating on one of the .net application crash on WinCE. The application crashes suddenly and no exception is thrown. I know that on Desktop environment there is event viewer where we can get some idea about error code or any other info. My question is, Is there any similar mechanism available in Windows CE?

Thanks,
Omky

Answer (score 1):

No, Windows CE does not have a system event log, so there's no associated viewer either.  You must add logging to your own application.  Have you added an [UnhandledException handler](http://www.danielmoth.com/Blog/appdomainunhandledexception-part-1.aspx)?